# set height of uicollectionviewcell according to imagecontent size in it which is loaded in a background thread

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to change the uicollectionviewcell height according to the image in it.However the loading of the image takes some time and it is in a separate thread.So how do i return the height of the cell in the following method

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(FRGWaterfallCollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
 heightForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     PFObject *image =_media[indexPath.row];
     PFFile *userImageFile = image[@"mediaFile"];

    int height=nil;
    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

           __block height=image.size.height;
        }
    }];



    return height;
}
```

i know that this method wont work as height would be nil everytime.pls suggest a working solution.

Comment: You should have a static height for collection cells that haven't yet loaded then call `reloadData` when a new image loads.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to achieve your requirements-

1) In your modal you should keep track of the image, whether it's downloaded or not.

2) Insert a check in `collectionView:layout:heightForItemAtIndexPath:`
method to return a default height in case the image is not downloaded else get the `image.size.height` and calculate the height of the cell from it.

3) Inside the method to create a collection view cell item insert a check to see if image is available or not, if it's available then set the image and return the cell else schedule the image for download here in BackGround thread and meanwhile return a default cell without image. When the image is downloaded switch to main thread, update the model data related to the cell to keep track that the image is downloaded for this cell and reload row for the same cell.

4) Calling reload on main thread to reload the cell for which the image is download triggers the datasource methods of the collection view for the corresponding row (i.e for the respective row 2 and 3 steps will again be followed).

5) Since, after downloading the image we have updated the model and called to reload row for the respective cell, so this time as the image is there in the modal for the respective row so the height will be calculated accordingly and the cell will be returned with the image.

These are just the steps to achieve your requirements, you need to convert the above steps to the code.